# Irreducible components of a cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $B=A\oplus S^1\oplus S^2\dots$ is a graded ring, $B$ is generated by $S^1$, $C=\textrm{Spec}B$ is called a cone over $X=\textrm{Spec}A$. We have natural projection $\pi\colon C\to X$. Moreover, we assume $A,B$ are coordinate rings of varieties.

Suppose $F_k$ is the locus of points in $X$ whose fiber dimension is exactly $k$. Suppose $Z$ is an irreducible component of $\overline{F_k}$.

Is $\pi^{-1}(Z)$ an irreducible component of $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true, and the blowing up of the origin in the plane is a counterexample:  $A$ is $k[s,t]$, and $B$ is $k[s,t,u,v]/\langle ut-sv\rangle$.

Comment: Is there a counterexample if we require $C\to X$ to be birational?

Comment: @mqx: "Is there a counterexample if we require $C\to X$ to be birational?"  There is a section $\sigma:X\to C$ given by forming the quotient of $B$ by the homogeneous ideal $B_+$ generated by elements of positive degree.  Thus, if $\pi$ is birational, then $\sigma(X)$ is an irreducible component of $C$.  Thus, if $F_k$ is nonempty for any $k>0$, then $C$ has at least one additional irreducible component.